# VB macro to identify different combinations of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have 4 columns of data.

- A is process step
- C is Risk number
- D is risk rating (high, moderate or low)
- F is a risk moderator (control, monitor, test or blank).

I need to populate a presentation with the different combinations.

- How many risks have controls and how many do not?
- of the ones with controls, how many have monitors or tests, how many do not?
- of the ones without controls how many have monitors or tests and how many do not?
- within those different categories how many are high, moderate and low?
- for the final box those without controls, monitors or tests, what process steps do the risks belong to?

Each risk effectively has a block occupied by column F containing mitigations. There can be several boxes with different items or they can be blank if there are no mitigators.

Below is code that identifies with or without controls but I am stuck on the next sections (counting the different risk ratings and breaking it further into with/without monitoring or testing.

```
Sub CountWithWithoutControlsv6()
    Const RiskColumn As String = "C"
    Const ControlColumn As String = "F"
    Const StartAtRow As Long = 7

    Dim r As Long
    Dim ControlFound As Boolean
    Dim control As Long
    Dim WoControl As Long

    Dim lastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Range(RiskColumn & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        r = .Range(ControlColumn & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        If lastRow < r Then
            lastRow = r
        End If

        ControlFound = False
        For r = StartAtRow To lastRow
            If UCase(Trim(CStr(.Cells(r, ControlColumn).Value))) = "CONTROL" Then
                ControlFound = True
            End If
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(r + 1, RiskColumn)) Then
                'Store info for previous block each time we encounter a new "risk"
                If ControlFound Then
                    control = control + 1
                Else
                    WoControl = WoControl + 1
                End If
                ControlFound = False
            End If
        Next
        'Store info for final "block"
        If ControlFound Then
            control = control + 1
        Else
            WoControl = WoControl + 1
        End If
    End With

    MsgBox control & "  = number of risks with controls, " & WoControl & "  = number of risks without controls"
End Sub
```

Comment: This sounds like something a pivottable could potentially do...

Comment: I was thinking that, if results were only going to be required for a few combinations of the "risk mitigators", it would be relatively simple to add that to the existing code (there would only be 2x2x2 different possible situations) but, because you also want results for process steps and results for risk rating it is just going to be unmanageable.  So, as an answer, I have proposed that you flatten your data and then just use Excel formulae to do what you want, PivotTables would also be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you "flatten" your data so that column A contains the process step, C is Risk number, D is risk rating (high, moderate or low), F indicates whether a "control" risk moderator exists, G indicates whether a "monitor" risk moderator exists, and H indicates whether a "test" risk moderator exists.

So instead of having data such as

```
A      C         D        F
Step1  Risk7     High     control
                          monitor
                          test
Step2  Risk8     Low      (blank)
```

you would instead have

```
A      C         D        F       G       H
Step1  Risk7     High     Yes     Yes     Yes
Step2  Risk8     Low      No      No      No
```

Once in that format, it would be simple to use Excel formulae such as `=COUNTIFS(F:F,"Yes",G:G,"Yes",H:H,"No")`.

Comment: Totally agree. Converting the data into a flat and 'safe' format would be the far better way to go.

Comment: @YowE3K thank you for the suggestion; great idea.  figured out how to write it to populate columns f, g and h with yes or no based on the control monitor test column.  from there it was an easy step to filter or pivot table the combinations I needed .  thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you followed your current approach to this problem you would ultimately achieve your goals - and the code itself would be straightforward to write. However, it would take an awfully long time to write to cover all of your cases and would be mind-numbingly tedious to write. (That you've only produced a few lines of what is, in all honesty, quite a trivial task is probably the reason for your downvote.)

However, before you launch into the remainder of the code, perhaps you would consider using ADO. It's ideally suited to this task and could complete your project in just a few lines. I've no desire to solve your problem for you, but I would like to offer some code to get you started together with a couple of query samples. I've used early binding which means I've referenced the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library (Tools ~> References...), but you could late bind if you wish.

Have a look at the code below and see if you could use it:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim connStr As String
Dim sqlStr As String
Dim tableName As String
Dim procField As String
Dim numField As String
Dim levelField As String
Dim controlField As String

connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
          "Data Source='C:\Users\User\Documents\StackOverflow\ADOexample.xlsm';" & _
          "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"

'Define the table and field names
With Sheet1 'change to your sheet
    tableName = .Name
    procField = CStr(.Cells(1, "A").Value)
    numField = CStr(.Cells(1, "C").Value)
    levelField = CStr(.Cells(1, "D").Value)
    controlField = CStr(.Cells(1, "F").Value)
End With

'Open the connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open connStr

'Some sample queries
'Sample 1
Set rs = New Recordset
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM [" & tableName & "$]" & _
         " WHERE [" & controlField & "] IS NOT NULL;"

rs.Open sqlStr, conn
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(numField)
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

'Sample 2
Set rs = New Recordset
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM [" & tableName & "$]" & _
         " WHERE [" & levelField & "] = 'H'" & _
         " AND ([" & controlField & "] = 'MONITOR'" & _
         " OR [" & controlField & "] = 'TEST');"

rs.Open sqlStr, conn
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(numField)
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

'Clean up objects
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```